Create directory on startup in Spring project
I am trying to create directories on startup in spring project. The values of the directory are defined in a properties file.
I saw this post How to create a directory on statup in spring boot project but the solution is only for spring boot project, not spring.
Do you have an idea of how to do the same solution for spring 5.3 ?
Thanks.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I tend to use a single InitializingBean which does all my initialization logic. I find this easier than multiple InitializingBeans since it's easier to control the ordering
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {
   ...

   @Bean
   public InitializingBean initializer(
      @Value("${input.dir}") inputDir,
      @Value("${output.dir}") outputDir
   ) {
      return () -> {
         new File(inputDir).mkdirs();
         new File(outputDir).mkdirs();
      };
   }
}

If you find that there's issues with ordering you may need to use the @Order annotation. See @Order in spring

Hello thanks for your answer. I saw somewhere Initializing approach is not recommended because the code will be closely linked to Spring. @lance-java

So do you know if using a composent and declaring its bean in config xml file would be enough ? And in case of multi module spring project, what would be the better approach ? Thanks.

You could do this in xml, just define a bean that implements InitializingBean
